Did I troubleshoot this 3-way socket correctly?
I'm trying to troubleshoot a floor lamp with a 3-way switch.  Right now, it turns on/off only when I turn the knob.  That is, it acts like a regular switch.  For some reason, one "half" of the bulb is not coming on.  Another post on this site suggested that this can be caused either by the bulb failing (it is a 3-way LED) or by a bad socket, and I want to know which before I replace.  I tested with a multimeter and got:

Between hot of the plug and the outer ring of the socket: infinite


Between hot of the plug and the inner contact on the bottom of the socket: depending on the position of the switch, toggles between infinite and a small value such as 1-3 ohms.


Between hot of the plug and the outer contact on the bottom of the socket: regardless of the position of the switch, always infinite.


Between the neutral of the plug and the ring on the socket: approx. 1 ohm


Between the neutral of the plug and either of the contacts on the bottom of the socket, infinite.

I also checked the resistance between the contacts on the LED 3-way bulb:

Between outer ring and first ring: 5.5 mega ohms


Between outer ring and second ring on bottom: 5.1 mega ohms

Based on this, I conclude that the switch is broken but the bulb is OK.  Am I right?

yes, you are partially right ... your conclusion about the bulb is incorrect ... also, your measurements are incomplete ... a plug has more than just a hot prong

@jsotola I edited to add the measurements from the neutral of the plug.

@jsotola please elaborate on how I am partially right.  Is it that the switch is definitely broken but the bulb not necessarily working based on my measurements?

it's not an incandescent lamp, so measuring resistance does not determine fitness

@manassehkatz-Moving2Codidact I also checked the resistance between the contacts on the LED 3-way bulb


Between hot of the plug and the outer contact on the bottom of the socket: regardless of the position of the switch, always infinite.

This image from Wikipedia by user:Icysubdweller, CC BY-SA 3.0, https://commons.wikimedia.org/w/index.php?curid=25088342 shows the details:

Since you never get a connection between hot and the outer contact on the bottom, either the switch is broken or the contact is disconnected in some way.
Most likely the problem is the switch, but the only way to tell for sure is to take apart the switch.
